# Python - 'function' object has no attribute 'langName'

Tags: python, panda3d

i'm trying to make something in Python.
I'm trying to import a variable from another file but it doesn't appear to work... as it gives this

```
   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'langName'
```

Here's the snippet which contains the variable (class is L10N - PS: not in the same code)

```
def buildName(self):
   langName = 'names_'+self.language.upper()+'.txt'
   print 'Current Loaded Names:'+langName()+'.'
   return langName
```

and the part where i try to import (this is where the error is):

```
names = [l.strip('\n\r').split('*')[1:] for l in open(pp+'data/etc/'+l10n.buildName.langName+'',"r").readlines() if not l.startswith('#')]
```

Anyways to fix it? I imported it and i'm not sure it would work.

EDIT:
    TypeError: unbound method buildName() must be called with l10n instance as first
 argument (got nothing instead)

Now gives this. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with the code. The first is in `buildName`, and I've commented it:

```
def buildName(self):
    langName = 'names_'+self.language.upper()+'.txt'
    print 'Current Loaded Names:'+langName+'.'   # <-- removed parens
    return langName  # <-- this is returned. no need to try to access outside the func
```

The second is in the call to that. `l10n.buildName` needs to be called, which returns `langName` for you, which doesn't need to be looked up.

```
names = [l.strip('\n\r').split('*')[1:] for l in open(pp+'data/etc/'+l10n.buildName()+'',"r").readlines() if not l.startswith('#')]
```

Comment: Fixed but now it gives this:                                             ''TypeError: unbound method buildName() must be called with l10n instance as first argument (got nothing instead)''

Comment: There's not enough information to know for sure what the cause is of that. Make sure l10n is an *instance* of your class, not the class itself. If that doesn't do the trick, you should accept an answer here and post that as a new question

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet

langName is a name, so you can't use `()` which is to invoke function

```
def buildName(self):
   langName = 'names_'+self.language.upper()+'.txt'
   print 'Current Loaded Names:'+langName+'.'
   return langName
```

Removed `()` from `langName()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another issue: you want to call a function `l10n.buildName()`, but instead you are trying to access function's local variable by doing `l10n.buildName.langName`. That is not possible

Since you are trying to get attribute `langName` from `l10n.buildName` function you get `'function' object has no attribute 'langName'` exception